# How to prove there is a „finest” block diagonalizing permutation matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us consider a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in {{\mathbb{C}}^{N\times M}}$ and two permutation matrices ${{\mathbf{P}}_{r}}\in {{\left\{ 0,1 \right\}}^{N\times N}}$ and ${{\mathbf{P}}_{c}}\in {{\left\{ 0,1 \right\}}^{M\times M}}$ which block diagonalizes $\mathbf{A}$: $${{\mathbf{P}}_{r}}\mathbf{A}{{\mathbf{P}}_{c}}=\text{diag}\left( {{\mathbf{A}}_{1}},{{\mathbf{A}}_{2}},\ldots ,{{\mathbf{A}}_{K}} \right)$$
where $K>1$ and ${{\mathbf{A}}_{i}}\in {{\mathbb{C}}^{{{N}_{i}}\times {{M}_{i}}}}$. How to prove there is a „finest” block diagonalizing permutation matrices ${{\mathbf{{P}'}}_{r}}$ and ${{\mathbf{{P}'}}_{c}}$ with maximal $K$?

Comment: Am I missing something? Since $K\leq\min\{M,N\} $, there are only finitely many values to choose from.

Comment: No, my question is if there is a "finer" couple of permutation P'(r) and P'(c) in case of block diagonalizable matrices A(i) (i=1,2,..,K).

Comment: I am looking forward your answering.

Comment: I have no idea what you expect. Because of finiteness, there is always a "finest" diagonalization; so whether there is a finer one depends on whether you are starting with the finest or not.

Comment: Suppose that P(r)*A*P(c)=diag(A(1),A(2)) and A(1) is block diagonalizable. How to choose a couple of P'(r) and P'(c) block diagonalizing A(1)? Do not these permutations "destroy" the former ordering referred to the matrix A(2)?

Comment: They do not destroy anything: you would put the permutations that work on $A (1) $ on the upper left corner and complete with ones in the diagonal to not do anything to the other blocks.